# Translating plurals in first-order logic

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

Using the dictionary
P: ...wakes up earlier than...

I am asked to translate the sentence:

"The earliest riser wakes up earlier than the latest riser"

which I have translated successfully - but I am then also asked to translate:

"The earliest risers wake up earlier than the latest risers"

which seems like there is no alternative way to translate. Is there?

Comment: Add examples of the predicates you are working with and how you managed to deal with the first sentence

Comment: Forgot to include the other predicate I can use, which is Q: ...is a person. So there is that, and P: ...wakes up earlier than...

I formalised the first sentence as:

$\exists x \forall y(Qx \land Qy \land\lnot x=y\implies Pxy \land \exists z \forall x' ((Qz \land Qx' \land \lnot z=x' \implies Px'z) \land Pxz))$

Answer (score 1):

I'd say this.

$\forall x \lnot\exists y(Qx \land Qy \land\lnot x=y\land Pyx) \land \forall w \lnot\exists z(Qw \land Qz \land\lnot w=z\land Pwz) \land Pxw$

But I'm waiting a feedback from you because it seems all too easy and - as usual with natural language translations - some semantic aspects are not satisfying. Interesting exercise btw.

Actually I found a specific article [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plural_quantification) from which you seem to be totally right: some plurals from NL to FOL are a big problem that apparently requires the introduction of specific "plural" variables and a specific relation "x is one of".